# html5 window.localStorage.getItemItem get keys that start with

Tags: javascript, html

How could I use

`window.localStorage.getItem();`

to specify items in localstarage that start with the string `'QQ'`. In my case the key can be: QQ + 3 digits, so I just need to specify that it starts with the string `'QQ'`...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't, get all the items and check them individually (code not tested):

```
var results = [];
for (i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {
    key = window.localStorage.key(i);
    if (key.slice(0,2) === "QQ") {
        results.push(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key)));
    }
}
```

If you want to do queries use something like [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).

Comment: You are a genius :)

Answer (score 8):

Came across this and here is a solution in es6 :

```
let search = 'QQ';
let values = Object.keys(localStorage)
                   .filter( (key)=> key.startsWith(search) )
                   .map( (key)=> localStorage[key] );
```

Comment: The best newer answer, but write out full functions instead of using arrow functions and switch `key.startsWith` out for `key.match(search)` (where search is something like `"#^startsWithText#"`) for it to work in IE/older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( var info in window.localStorage ){
 if ( info.substring( 0 , 2 ) === "QQ"){
  var data = window.localStorage.getItem( info ) );
  console.log(info);
 }
```

code not tested

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
 var keyIndex = 0;
 var thisKey = window.localStorage.key(keyIndex);

 while(thisKey != '' && thisKey != undefined)
 {
    if (thisKey.substr(0, 2) == 'QQ')
    {
       // do whatever you need to do with thisKey
    }

    keyIndex+= 1;
    thisKey = window.localStorage.key(keyIndex);
 }
```

But robertc's solution is right too, it's a bit more simple that way. I actually changed my code to do a for loop too.